# Intellij doesn't recognize Groovy tests properly

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, groovy, spock

I have test written in spock. Each time when I'm running tests IntelliJ saying that the configuration is wrong - but if I press apply and etc I'm able to run these tests - What I can do, to don't see these messages?

1. Example of test for which I'm getting this error message:

[image]

2. The configuration which opens after an attempt of running the test:

[image]

3. Last error message:

[image]

Any ideas how to get rid of these?

For now I have created [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209187).

Comment: Looks like a bug, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce.

Comment: Ok, done https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209187 thanks

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA JUnit configuration stores method name and parameters signature in a single string instance.

While this works for Java (it doesn't allow parentheses in methods names), this fails for other JVM languages.

This issue is not related to Spock, it's reproducible for arbitrary JUnit test class written in Groovy.

[Follow YouTrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209187) for updates.